# Multiple instances of site in one webrole with different web.config

Tags: azure

I would like to deploy my MVC3 app to Azure using multiple physical sites of the same app.
It's great that I can use the sites element in ServiceDefinition.csdef to do this.

But I want each of the sites to connect to a different database. The connection string is in the web.config. Is there an easy way to do this, besides logging into the vm and changing it by hand?

Answer (score 1):

You could register a startup task to go and modify/move the web.config files when the VM starts up. It's a bit messy, but cleaner than doing it by hand!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456327.aspx

Comment: Windows Azure VM are not persisted so doing anything by RDP to VM is not suggested at all. Also when the VM is ready and role is already up to making any change in web.config will not be available to IIS application. You best bet is to create solution directly in your role itself.

Comment: @Avkash You mean by fetching the connection string from another source in code?

Answer (score 1):

[Answer to your comment] - With Windows Azure (actually with any PaaS solution) The first rule of thumb is that when the role starts all the configuration should be ready and the second rule of thumbs is that nothing should be done in VM through RDP access, because changes will not persist. Due to this required configuration either deployed in Azure Package or modified directly from start up task.

[Answer to your question]
In Windows Azure you can run multiple sites within one Web Role however they all should share the same main web.config because multiple sites are running within one Web Role. Here is how you can do it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433110.aspx

Now as your requirement is to have multiple databases, so in your web.config you can add multiple database connection string as below:
`$`

```
 <ConnectionString>
 <Add name="DB1" connectionString="Data Source=DS1.........."/>
 <Add name="DB2" connectionString="Data Source=DS2.........."/>
 </ConnectionString>
```

once you have above, in your ASP.NET code you can enumerate these connection strings and use with specific sites as described in the given example:

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/780-how-to-use-multiple-database-connection.aspx

Finally, you can add multiple sites with your web role during development and can also have specific DB connection specified in web.config so I dont think there is any need to use startup task at all or do something in VM, unless i am missing something here.