# Customising web.config when publishing a multi-tenant project to Azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment, multi-tenant

I have a VS2012 solution that contains a multi-tenant MVC web project that I want to publish to multiple websites on a single Azure web role.  I've changed my `.csdef` so that it contains multiple sites like so:

```
<Sites>
  <Site name="Web">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
  <Site name="Web2" physicalDirectory="..\..\..\[source dir]">
    <Bindings>
      <Binding name="Endpoint1" endpointName="Endpoint1" hostHeader="secondsite.com" />
    </Bindings>
  </Site>
</Sites>
```

My question is: how can I deploy a different version of the Web.config to each site as part of the publication process in order to accommodate the different tenants?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to inform you the following,
When it comes to tenant based configurations, it will be ideal to consider having the configurations in the Database than to duplicate the Web.config files.

If you consider using a pure form of multi-tenancy which uses a single code base and maintains all the tenant based configurations in the database identified by the tenant id, there is no requirement to duplicate or create a copy of a web.config files.

The process will be like this, you identify the tenant from the login credentials and then use that tenant id to fetch the configuration metadata and then apply them throughout the application.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to respond, it's much appreciated.  My situation is such that I need to solve the problem described in the question, deploying different web.config files with each site, rather than changing the architecture to a more 'pure' form of multi-tenancy.

Comment: Please take a look at the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10434553/multiple-instances-of-site-in-one-webrole-with-different-web-config

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a particularly elegant solution, but in the end I went for a two step publication process.

In the first step I publish to the local file system adding in a custom build target that runs after `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage`.  In this target I copy the packaged files to the deployment directories (1 for each site) and execute a  `TransformXml` on each of the clones in order to change the Web.config.

The second step was simply to publish to Azure using the deployment directories as the source by pointing the `<Site physicalDirectory="..." />` at location of the cloned output files.